# How can I rotate this noise texture and disrupt its ideal pattern?

Tags: texturing, materials

How can I rotate this noise pattern (achieved by setting 0 to Scale X value) as illustrated by the red lines without rotateing the plane? I tried tweaking Rotation settings in the Mapping nodes but it doesn't change the direction of the lines.

Also, how can I create a pattern with parallel lines of  random lengths from it?

[image]

My Blend File: [Stretching Noise Texture](https://filebin.net/03y1oy6pfrepd812)

Update:
 Ahh I figured out how to rotate it. It's embarassing that it's as simple as setting the Y value to 0. Yet there's one question that remains.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I didn't understand which is your goal, could you upload a rough picture of the pattern you're looking for?

Comment: I'm sorry for being ambiguous. My goal is illustrated by the red lines, which is to create parallel lines of different lengths from the noise texture.